# How can I get an environment variable representing my machine ip?

Tags: boot, 18.04, environment-variables

I'm not sure how the scope of variables in `/etc/environment` works, nor when they get created, but I need a "global" environment variable that is populated with the ip address after a DHCP address is assigned so I can use that variable just like any variable defined in `/etc/environment`

For example, I assign hard-coded variables in `/etc/environment` such as:

```
TZ="America/New_York"
```

I can then use `${TZ}` in **yml* configuration files and they will be populated with value assigned in `/etc/environment`

I need to be able to use `${ipv4}` in my **yml** files which will have the machine's ip address (which is assigned via DHCP).  How can I create this, keeping in mind I might not log into the machine.

I've done a little research and I know I can populate a value with the ip address by running the following executed from a bash prompt will populate `foo` with the correct ip.

```
foo=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list enp0s3 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
```

ETA:  Since my machine gets assigned an ip from my router's MAC address filtering option, I won't expect my ip to ever change *unless* I do so from the router, which I tend to do from time to time.  So this is why I'm not hard coding the actual value into the file

Comment: Look into using the `/etc/profile` file or creating a script in `/etc/profile.d/` folder that will run your command to set the `foo` as a global variable.

Comment: Don't those only get executed upon login?

Comment: This all depends on why you need to know what your IP address is.  The host is already named for localhost.  Localhost is a global variable already to the system.  And yes, the profile would be only run at login.  Or if you added it to `~/.bashrc` would run on every time you launched a terminal window, but that is not global and is only used in the present terminal session.  If you added it to your `~/.profile` file, it would have to be sourced every time you wish to use it.  You can source any file at any time.  `. /etc/profile` would source the file at that time.

Comment: Your `~/.profile` file is sourced at login as well.

Comment: I need to know the ip address the DHCP server hands out to this machine, and I need it *after* it is assigned and not before waiting for someone to login, much less having a kludge to auto-login.  So after the login window appears, I'd like to have XXX=192.168.1.46

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do.  I get the wanting what your IP address is, but to get it at anytime, it requires that someone be logged in to get that info.  The `/etc/profle` is global that means anyone logging in will get it.    If you are trying to find out what the IP address is from a remote system you would get that from DNS or the DHCP server itself.

Comment: A server can boot and get a DHCP address without anyone logging in.

Comment: That is correct.  But how do you get that IP address that it was assigned if you are not logged into that host or you are trying to connect to it from another system? That is where you use DNS or DHCP to find it. I am assuming then that when you mean Environment or Global is that you mean your network itself and not just the computer.  `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` are for the computer only and not for the rest of the network.